# React Native ScrollView not scrolling when keyboard is open

Tags: android, react-native

Here is a demo of the problem: https://rnplay.org/apps/zqmeDg

Also, you'll notice that the whole viewport shifts up when keyboard opens.
This problem has halted development of our product in its final stages.

I have also filed a github issue for the same:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6757

Please help

Comment: Finally got it working, thanks to the help provided by @Bema. Details Can be viewed here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the keyboard to shift the viewport you have to set that in Android's manifest file (android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml). Just add the line bellow to your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

You can find more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

The scrolling issue is strange and unfortunatelly I couldn't run your demo to try to figure it out, but take a look at [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) and [scrollEnabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollenabled) props in your ScrollView element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, do you know if there is any way to read `keyboardOpen` and `keyboardClose` events on android. `DeviceEventEmitter` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Also, `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` seems to be doing the trick of keeping the topbar in its place. However, the scroll-view is still unresponsive.

Comment: I think the keyboard events you are after are keyboardDidOpen, keyboardDidClose, also, scrolling issue could be because your ScrollView is too big?